# Prove that there are rational polynomials $p,q$ such that $p(x)(x^4+2x^2+1)+ q(x)(x^4-3x^2-4) = x^2+1$

Tags: polynomials

> 1. Prove that there are polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that: 
>      $$p(x)(x^4+2x^2+1)+ q(x)(x^4-3x^2-4) = x^2+1$$
> 2. Is it still true if we replace $x^2+1$ with $x+5 $?

So:

1. I know how to prove this: it's by the Polynomial remainder theorem.
2. Someone told me that I need to move to the complex field, and put in the value $x =i $ to get $0 = 0 $,  but if we replace $x^2+1$ in $x+5$ we will get $0 =i+5 $, which is false; therefore it is not true for $x+5$, but I don't understand this explanation because our field is $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and not complex.

Comment: But it sits inside a complex field, so the method is legitimate.

Comment: Can you explain it more detailed please?

Comment: If an identity is true, then it's still true when the coefficients are imagined as complex, so it should still give equality when evaluated at a complex argument.

Comment: If you don't like that method, you can instead note that $x^2+1$ divides the left side but doesn't divide $x+5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $(x^{2} + 1) | (x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1)$ and $(x^{2} + 1) | (x^{4} - 3x^{2} - 4)$ and hence it divides $p(x)(x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1) + q(x)(x^{4} - 3x^{2} - 4)$. If this expression was $(x + 5)$ then we would have $x^{2} + 1$ divide $x + 5$ which is non-sense. Hence the $x^{2} + 1$ in part 1 can't be replaced by $x + 5$. The reason part 1 holds is because of the Euclid's algo for GCD of $(x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1)$ and $(x^{4} - 3x^{2} - 4)$

Answer (score 0):

> our field is Q[x] and not complex.

A polynomial over $Q$ can be evaluated at any complex number, or at any number in any field containing $Q$ (such as $Q(\sqrt{-1}$ for this problem) and if the formula with $p$ and $q$ holds in $Q[X]$ it will hold after evaluation.

The question can be avoided by writing the argument as

> there is no solution of the equation  $$p(x)(\cdots) + q(x)(\dots) = x+5 + (x^2+1)r(x)$$ because [...] and therefore none with $r(x)=0$